# Azure Function App cosmosdb input binding - read from nested json

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following json sent to an Azure Function App:

```json
{
"a" : {
  "nested" : {
    "object" : "hello_world"
    }
  }
}
```

Within the **function.json** I would like to fetch a document based on the `object` value (`hello_world` in this example) :

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "doc_in",
      "databaseName": "my_db",
      "collectionName": "my_collection",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AZURE_COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM my_db as db WHERE db.my_field = {a.nested.object}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

**init.py**

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, doc_in: func.In[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    if doc_in:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"msg":"A document was found!"}),
            status_code=200,
            mimetype="application/json" 
            )
```

The `SELECT * FROM my_db as db WHERE db.my_field = {a.nested.object}` query does not work and return a **HTTP 404** code and there's no much information [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#queue-trigger-look-up-id-from-json-4).

Does someone know how am I supposed to set the input json file into the cosmos query ?

Comment: The JSON is not valid. JSON should be a valid object.

Comment: Sorry I did the typo while simplifying the json document for the so question - that's fixed now

Comment: The input parameter is called `req`. Somehow you need to read from the JSON from the input parameter. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Have you tried to run it with the correct JSON? According to the docs, it should work with `departmentId` being on the first level of the JSON: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python#queue-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-sqlquery-3

Comment: You can just receive JSON, parse it by yourself, then just read from Cosmos DB by yourself, without bindings. That's how it can be done in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63343183/3503521

Comment: I would like it better not having to implement the code by myself. Using input binding works pretty well when using query parameters and it souds like I should be able to use json as well as an input.

Comment: For some reason I cannot get it to work even though I am setting my value at first level. I keep hitting a 404

Comment: It's hard to find any docs ‍♂️